# PyCharm 2018.1 update broke new project creation

Tags: python, pycharm, pyodbc

This feels like a crap question but I am too new to know what details to look for or include. I've been using python less than a month for data analysis, and was told that I would likely find the combination of Anaconda and PyCharm helpful, and I have.

Recently Pycharm was updated to 2018.1 and since then my imports on new projects don't seem to be working properly.

i.e. I use pyodbc for some data import. I literally copy pasted the code from a prior project and then installed the package (ie right click install pyodbc which completes "successful"). I am getting

> "pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!')"

For giggles I built new sub scripts in the old project files and duplicated them in the new project files, they work in the old but not the new.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Further investigation shows the that virtual environment was previously being created as a sub of the project folder, where now it is being created in a separate folder. Not sure how to adjust that nor whether it will be impactful.

Comment: Standing recommendation: whenever a new version of your IDE breaks your workflow, roll back to the old version ASAP.